# Why bash does not spawn a subshell for simple commands?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, subshell

Consider the two following bash commands. One creates a subshell and the other does not.

**No subshell**

```
$ bash -c "sleep 10000 "
```

pstree output:

```
bash,100648
  └─sleep,103509 10000
```

**With subshell**

```
$ bash -c "sleep 10000; sleep 99999 "


bash,100648
  └─bash,103577 -c sleep 10000; sleep 99999
      └─sleep,103578 10000
```

Is this some kind of an optimization ? Bash looks at the command and skips the process creation for simple commands. It looks like the simple command is spawned by the parent terminal’s bash.

---

Bash version I am using is

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Though, I think the same can be observed in bash 3.X too.

---

Some more examples. 
With builtins the subshell gets spawned. Builtins are not executed in the parent bash.

```
$ bash -c "read"

bash,100648
  └─bash,104336 -c read
```

---

Same behavior with `sleep` can be reproduced with `top` and with output redirect.

```
$ bash -c "top -b "
bash,100648
  └─top,104392 -b
```

And

```
$ bash -c "top -b > /dev/null "
bash,100648
  └─bash,104420 -c top -b > /dev/null
      └─top,104421 -b
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928932/2072269

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, the shell with PID 100648 is your interactive shell, while `sleep` is in fact the process that replaced `bash -c ''` process.  The [`execve()` syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) spawns a new program which retains the PID of the original process that called it, hence why you don't see that original `bash -c ''` there. The simple reason for why simple commands replace shell process is because it saves resources as explained in [Stephane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466523/85039) to [Why is there no apparent clone or fork in simple bash command and how it's done?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466496/why-is-there-no-apparent-clone-or-fork-in-simple-bash-command-and-how-its-done/466523#466523).

This is also evident from a simple test in one terminal:

```
$ echo $$
10250
$ bash -c 'sleep 60'
```

And in another:

```
$ pstree -p 10250
bash(10250)───sleep(21031)
```

As for why it happens this way, is because there's just a simple command without pipes, and `bash` [performs direct execve for simple commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466505/85039).

Exactly for that reason, `bash` recognizes you have multiple command statements in the second example, hence for each `sleep` command you have in `"sleep 10000; sleep 99999 "`. In the first case, `execve()` can just replace the parent process and when the new exits - no problem. But here shell can't exit after the first command completes. Hence there will be fork and execve for `sleep 10000` which is what you see in the output of `pstree` and later a new fork and execve for `sleep 99999`

---

Another test you can perform to believe that simple command in `bash -c ''` replaces the shell process is this:

```
$ bash -c 'grep "^Pid:" /proc/self/status /proc/$$/status'
/proc/self/status:Pid:  23946
/proc/23946/status:Pid: 23946
```

Note, that such behavior is bash-specific. For `/bin/dash` on Debian-based distros (and also evident in `strace` , too):

```
$ sh -c 'grep "^Pid:" /proc/self/status /proc/$$/status'
/proc/self/status:Pid:  24188
/proc/24187/status:Pid: 24187
```

Answer (score 3):

The output of `pstree` is misleading.

```
bash -c "sleep 10000 "
```

does create a bash child process. But this process does not create another child process. Because there is nothing more to do after running `sleep` the shell makes a direct `execve()` to `sleep` without forking first.

Because this is so fast you just see the result after the `execve` in `pstree`.

But in the

```
bash -c "sleep 10000; sleep 99999 "
```

case the new bash forks twice, once for each command. It could make an `execve` to the last command, too, instead of forking first. I don't know why it does not.

This and the redirection case are probably just problems with the detection when a fork is necessary.