# Why doesn't pid $$ refer to bash here?

Tags: bash, ps

In my Bash shell the `$$` variable [expands to the process ID of the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

So why does `ps` print its own name when I execute this?

```
$ bash -c 'ps -p $$ -o comm='
ps
```

When I follow it with a no-op command, `ps` does print the name of the shell.

```
$ bash -c 'ps -p $$ -o comm= && true'
bash
```

Versions:

- GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- ps from procps-ng 3.3.16

Comment: [Why bash does not spawn a subshell for simple comamands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466519) is another way of asking the same question. [Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466519) shows that the first example is a performance optimization on a simple command. I expected Bash to fork a new process, but instead it starts a process with the same pid and replaces itself. The second example is a compound command. Bash can't replace itself because it needs to supervise all the commands in the compound, so it forks each subprocess with a new pid and retains its own.

Comment: In particular, Bash needs to keep itself alive until `ps` exits so it can then run `true`  if needed. It wouldn't need to keep itself alive until `true` exits, though, but Bash only optimizes the case of a single command, not any tail-end command. However, ksh93 optimizes that too, e.g. `ksh -c 'ps -p $$ -o comm=; ps -p $$ -o comm='` prints `ksh`, `ps`